# Weird print view on IE8

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I made a layout like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLf5N.jpg) in bootstrap. It works fine on almost browsers, IE8 too. However, I turn this page to print preview on IE8 with Shrink to fit mode, it becomes like [this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azr3T.png)

I am tired of IE8. I try to add media print on my CSS, but IE crashes every time I turn to print preview and I have restart Win7 for not crashing next time.

How can I prevent these problems?

Comment: You need to include your code too.

Comment: I have a link of this page: https://shigeta-seibi.co.jp/inspection/seibi

Comment: You must provide the code **in the question itself**. NOT a link.

Comment: The code is very long. Can I post in the comment box?

Comment: It should not be a comment, it should be an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37692908/edit). You should also see about learning what an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is

Comment: thanks for your instruction